# How to go another Activity using function instead of Button widget

Tags: java, android

I hope if someone help me in this , 
in my projet I am trying to open another avtivity used voice command Ex, say "one " it should compare if the string is equal to what I? have it should switch to another activity or external activity such as Phone call, Camera. What I did here, I store the recognized ward in Edittext and store it in string and compare it . my 2 projects counted on how to do this

Inside `onCreate`:

```
    final Button btntx = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    final EditText edittxt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edttxt);
    btntx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_DIAL); // sow the Dial window
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"));
startActivity(intent);
   );

    }
    ////////////////////////// outside the onCreate //////// Function after I get the result from the Speech recognizer and  call this function to see if the what it said is equal to my keyword . SO i need to call the button to open that activity        

 String gwdata= edtxt.getText().toString(); // data from EditText
                if (gwdata.equals("One"))

                {
  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"They are equal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                     // Here Do someting to go to another activity 
                }
```

Thnks guys in advance .

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent (firstactivity.this,secondactivity.class); 
startActivity(intent);

Comment: Thank you , it was in front of me all the time , Thnks for help

Comment: Another question plz if you cold help.that answer when I wanna open another activity , but what If instead to open an activity , activate button widget .EX If what I said is equal , I need it to activate Button to do something instead of touch /press the button

Comment: There is no way to activate any button, you can enable or disable any button. Such as : button.setEnabled(true/false);

Comment: I see, another thing ,  Can I call function located outside the onCreate from other function located outside onCreate too . . Ex, I have two functions outside the onCreate , Call one from another .  I used to call function located outside  from function inside oncreate. So Am asking can the opposite done . I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Yes you can do that..and as I have given so many answers of yours,atleast upvote my comments..;-)

Comment: Thank you so much , I dont know how to up vote your comment